# Eclipse Plugin: Parse the Android Project source code to get the names of the methods used

Tags: java, android, parsing, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin and I want the names of the all the methods (which exists in the Android API) used in the Android Project source code. Does anyone know how should I parse the code?

Suppose my source code is:

```
package com.example.androidsample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;


public class MockLocationProvider {
  String providerName;
  Context ctx;

  public MockLocationProvider(String name, Context ctx) {
    this.providerName = name;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.addTestProvider(providerName, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, 0, 5);
    SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("Phone Number", null, "Message", null, null);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
  }

  public void pushLocation(double lat, double lon) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
      Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Location mockLocation = new Location(providerName);
    mockLocation.setLatitude(lat);
    mockLocation.setLongitude(lon); 
    mockLocation.setAltitude(0); 
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, mockLocation);
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
      Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.removeTestProvider(providerName);
  }
}
```

Then the list that I requies is something like:

```
[
getSystemService,
addTestProvider,
getDefault,
sendTextMessage,
setTestProviderEnabled,
setLatitude,
setLongitude,
setAltitude,
setTime,
setTestProviderLocation,
removeTestProvider
]
```

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar task.
I use [ASTParser](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) to get MethodDeclaration of each method in a class.
Then I use [getBody](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/MethodDeclaration.html) and parse each method deeper to statements.